# What should be the vertex and fragment shaders to draw a cube with texture in version 440 core

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I am following "Interactive Computer Graphics" by Ed Angel, specifically the code for rotating cube with texture. The vertex shader for this (as in the book) is as follows:

```
#version 150
in vec4 vPosition;
in vec4 vColor;
in vec2 vTexCoord;

out vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoord;
uniform vec3 theta;
void main()
{
........
........
// code for rotation
........
color = vColor;
texCoord = vTexCoord;
gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
}
```

And the fragment shader code is:

```
#version 150
in vec4 color;
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 fColor;
uniform sampler2D texture;
void main()
{
fColor = color * texture2D( texture, texCoord );
}
```

[The link for the complete code is [here](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/APPENDIX_A_EXAMPLES/WINDOWS_VERSIONS/). Just look at the code for `example 8`.

I am trying to implement this using `#version 440 core`. When I run this, I get only a black cube. The texture is not shown.

What change to the above code should I make to display the texture correctly?

Comment: Change texture2D to texture (but that is a minor thing). Acutally, if the shaders are not compatible with the version, you would get a compiler error.

Comment: @BDL I have tried with that as well. But the result is the same.

Comment: Try with 'fColor = vec4(1.0);' If you get a white cube this way, the problem is probably with the way your texture is created/uploaded/bound.

Comment: @bernie I get the white cube as you have mentioned. Moreover, if I use `fcolor=color` I still get a colored cube. However, if I use `fColor = color * texture(checker_texture, texCoord)`, I get a black cube. I have copied the the texture part from the links I have given. Can you please check whether anything is missing in that code?

Comment: That confirms the problem is with the texture setup. I don't have time to crawl through a source tree like that (and you should not expect such help). Add the relevant parts (and only those) to your question to get help.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the cpp code:

```
glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 );
```

is your problem. glsl version 440 requires an OpenGL 4.4 context. Change it to :

```
glutInitContextVersion( 4, 4 );
```

And modernise your shader code according to:

[GLSL Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf)

And it should work fine.

Comment: I have already done that in my code but the result is the same. If the code for the texture loading is the same for glsl version `440`, I think, I have coded it correctly. With the shader code, please see my response to @bernie.

Comment: Which dev tools are you using (and which gpu do you have)?

Comment: And in line with the other responses, post your texture loading, set up and usage code